# Unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010

Tags: fpga, ftdi

I'm trying to build [this](https://github.com/SymbiFlow/prjtrellis/tree/master/examples/ecp5_evn) example for my ECP5 evaluation board. It runs fine until the upload to the FPGA is supposed to start. It then gives me this error:

```
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description 'Lattice ECP5 Evaluation Board', serial '*' at bus location '*'

make: *** [Makefile:18: prog] Error 1
```

Output of `lsusb`, notice that the device with vid 0403 and pid 6010 is there:

```
0403:6010 (bus 1, device 4) path: 1
1d6b:0002 (bus 1, device 1)
80ee:0021 (bus 2, device 2) path: 1
1d6b:0001 (bus 2, device 1)
```

Output of `dmesg` after connecting the device:

```
[   99.954483] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   99.954564] usb 1-1: Detected FT2232H
[   99.962509] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

I don't understand how it cannot find the device while it is right there. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS inside a virtual machine. I have installed the expansion pack and passed the usb device to this machine.

I have installed the following packages through apt install: libftdi-dev libftdi1 libusb-dev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to add permissions to access the device for the non-root users. I did this by creating the file /etc/udev/rules.d/ecp5.rules with the following contents:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="6010", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this Anteino  , would never have figured this out

Comment: No worries. It's one of those things..